# MyVisualForcePage does not exist or is not a valid override for action View. - Deployment Error

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, deployment, change-set

tried to deploy a a change set from 1 sandbox to another and it gives the error

> "MyVisualForcePage does not exist or is not a valid override for
>   action View"

.  I included the VF page so I'm guessing it has to do with the way I overrided the View of the custom object with my VF page. Any clues? Here's MyVisualForcePage just in case I missed something(though its working fine even after tests). Any help appreciated, still a newbie at all this. Thanks in advance

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="true" cache="false"     controller="GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller">
<style>
.activeTab {background-color: #236FBD; color:white;
background-image:none}
.inactiveTab { background-color: lightgrey; color:black;
background-image:none}
img {
max-width: none;
}
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>    
![enter image description here][1]<script>
    var map;
    var clat;
    var clong;

    function initialize() {

        // set the map options in the format that V3 of googlemaps expects
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 9,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(1.0931431 ,36.701831),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

        };
        // attach our map to the map_canvas div
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapOptions);


        // Pull the data in from the SOQL and use visualforce to create the javascript calls            
        <apex:repeat value="{!MeetingsList}" var="Meeting">        
            showAddress("{!JSENCODE(Meeting.Name)}", "Business Value:{!Meeting.Business_Value__c} {!Meeting.Meeting_Date__c} <a href='../{!Meeting.id}' target='_blank'>Details</a>", "{!Meeting.GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s}", "{!Meeting.GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s}", 1);
        </apex:repeat>

        <apex:repeat value="{!MeetingsList2}" var="Meeting">        
            showAddress("{!JSENCODE(Meeting.Name)}", "Business Value:{!Meeting.Business_Value__c} {!Meeting.Meeting_Date__c} <a href='../{!Meeting.id}' target='_blank'>Details</a>", "{!Meeting.GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s}", "{!Meeting.GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s}", 0);
        </apex:repeat>  

    } // function initialize()


    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);



    function showAddress(title, content, Lat, Long, locType) {

        // convert our raw values to the format that google expects                                 
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(Lat), parseFloat(Long));

        if (latlng != null) {

            // create an info window            
            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: content
            });

            // Create a marker on the map                   
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latlng,
                map: map,
                title: title                        
            });
            if(locType == 1){
                marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue-dot.png');
            } else {
                marker.setIcon('http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png');
                marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
                //Drawing circle
                var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
                    center: latlng,
                    radius: 20,
                    map: map,
                    fillOpacity: 0.2,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
                    strokeWeight: 1
                      });
                    cLat = Lat;
                    cLong = Long;
                    //var clatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(cLat), parseFloat(cLong));
                    var div = document.getElementById("textDiv");
                    div.textContent = cLat + " " + cLong;
                    var text = div.textContent;
                    //map.setCenter(clatLng)

                    }
            //map.panTo(latlng);
            // Add an event to the marker so the info window will appear when it is clicked
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map,marker);
                infowindow.setTitle("HTML");
                infowindow.setContent(content);
                map.setZoom(9);
                map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
            });

        } // check for null latlng due an error parsing

    } // end show address          

</script>
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="tabdetails"
    id="AccountTabPanel" tabClass="activeTab"
    inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab">
        <apex:tab label="Details" name="AccDetails" id="tabdetails">
            <apex:detail relatedList="true" title="true"/>
        </apex:tab>
        <apex:tab label="Group meetings map" name="Contacts" id="tabContact">
            <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:300px"></div>
        <div id="textDiv"></div>
        </apex:tab>
</apex:tabPanel>
```

Here is my controller class

```
public with sharing class GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller {

public List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList {get;set;}
public List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList2 {get;set;}

public GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller() {

    Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    MeetingsList = [SELECT Name, Group__r.Id, Business_Value__c, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__r.Id =:id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 1];
    MeetingsList2 =[SELECT Name, Group__r.Id, Business_Value__c, Meeting_Date__c, GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM Meeting__c WHERE Group__r.Id =:id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c DESC LIMIT 1];


} // end constructor


} // end class
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem is that (from [Overriding Standard Buttons and Tab Home Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=links_customize_override.htm&language=en_US)):

> When overriding buttons with a Visualforce page, only Visualforce
>   pages that use the standard controller for the object on which the
>   button appears can be selected

This means that your page needs to look like this (change "Account" to the type you want to override the view for):

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="true" cache="false"
        standardController="Account"
        extensions="GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller"
        >
```

and your controller must have this constructor:

```
public GoogleMap_Meeting_Controller(ApexPages.StandardController sc) {
    ....
}
```

Though that wouldn't explain why the problem only occurs in the org you are deploying to.

Comment: My guess is that the VF page was originally using a standard controller, then Kollo changed it to use a custom controller, so now it can't be used as an override.

Comment: @JeremyNottingham In the custom object the VF page was intended for, I had changed the view in Buttons, Links, and Actions to The VF page, but through a hack way of doing it. using an extension instead solved the problem